# Argument controller is not function, got undefined at Error

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, controller

I'm using AngularJS + Laravel for my web-application. AngularJS install in public/app folder, the view for my web-application is not from public/app, is from Laravel/app/view folder.

```
-views
--web-app
---partials
---chat-rooms.blade.php
--index.blade.php
```

**Index.blade.php**

```
<body ng-app='chatApp'>
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1> Chat application </h1>
    </div>
    <div ng-view class="container"></div>
    {{ HTML::script('app/libs/angular/angular.min.js')}}
    {{ HTML::script('app/libs/angular-route/angular-route.min.js')}}
    {{ HTML::script('app/scripts/app.js')}}
    {{ HTML::script('app/scripts/controllers/chat-rooms.js')}} 
</body>
```

**Chat-rooms.blade.php**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedChatRoom" ng-options="chatRoom.name for chatRoom in chatRooms">
    </select>
    <button type="button" ng-click="selectChatRoom(selectedChatRoom)">Select chat room</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="chatRoom.name" placeholder="Enter chat room name">
    <button type="button" ng-click="createChatRoom(chatRoom)">Create</button>
</div>
```

My app.js is from public/app folder :

```
'use strict';
angular.module('chatApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/chat-rooms',
        controller: 'ChatRoomsCtrl'
    })

    .when('/chat-room/:chatRoom', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/chat-room.html',
        controller: 'ChatRoomCtrl'
    });
});
```

The problem now is "ChatRoomsCtrl" cause this problem, the function is undefined. 
Here's the js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('chatApp')
.controller('ChatRoomsCtrl', function($scope, ChatRoom, $location) {


    var chatRoomsLoaded = function(chatRooms) {
        $scope.chatRooms = chatRooms;
    }

    var handleErrors = function(response) {
        console.error(response);
    }


    $scope.selectChatRoom = function(chatRoom) {

        $location.path('chat-room/' + chatRoom.id);
    }

    $scope.createChatRoom = function(chatRoom) {

        ChatRoom.create(chatRoom).then($scope.selectChatRoom);
    }


    ChatRoom.getAll()
        .then(chatRoomsLoaded)
        .catch(handleErrors);

});
```

Again, everything seems work, the front-end can work, but the backends couldn't. The create button "ng-click" doesn't toggle at all. Seems like controller is causing this.

---

Part of my index.blade.php is actually put inside my video template.
My video template consist of videoController and route...

**VideoController**

```
public function getChatRoom()
{
    return View::make('chat-app.partials.chat-rooms');
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('video/{slug}', array(
'as' => 'showVideo',
'uses' => 'VideoController@show'
));

Route::get('video/partials/chat-rooms', array(
'uses' => 'VideoController@getChatRoom'
));
```

When I load the chat-rooms, the web address must be video/partials/chat-rooms.. Currently I'm surfing the video template, part of it was chat-app, the web address is video/{slug}/ which slug could be any name...

**ERROR :** [Click here to view the error](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.11/ng/areq?p0=ChatRoomsCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined)

Comment: `controller: 'ChatRoomCtrl'` ? did you miss `s` because it looks like you only have `ChatRoomsCtrl` and not the one without an `s`?

Comment: That is what your pasted code says @ `.when('/chat-room/:chatRoom', {`

Comment: Do you also have a ChatRoomCtrl that is not shown?  Also when you run the app in your browser, does the console show any other errors, or does the network tab show that some URL is returning a 404 not found?  Maybe one of your paths is wrong.

Comment: The front-end webpage loads successfully without error. I open console window from chrome and determine the error. I found "controller" is not function, undefined. Has one warning "WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once." and this error in console.  @NicholasSmith

Comment: @AndroidBeginner your code pasted shows you are loading only one controller but referrring to 2 different in your route, i.e `ChatRoomsCtrl` and `ChatRoomCtrl` so if you load the one with the controller that is not registered you will see that error and btw what exactly is the complete error message say, which controller is missing?

Comment: .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/chat-rooms',
        controller: 'ChatRoomsCtrl'
    }) @PSL this controller

Comment: I took your code and put it into a plnkr example, tweaked a little to load some sample chat room data without having to call out to the ChatRoom service you didn't show.  It's working as-is.  I'm not sure what else is different with your app.  See http://plnkr.co/edit/O6hYDDRrEAm2f0X7gVV4?p=preview

Comment: @NicholasSmith Thanks but still won't work. Actually my link is localhost:9999/video/{slug}/ , I'm inserting "ng-app" into video template, so that part of video page is embed into chat-app. The .when('/') actually work with localhost:9999/video/{slug}/ .. but it shows the layout but button not functioning. ChatRoomsCtrl  not defined...

Comment: @AndroidBeginner How are you inserting ng-app="" on page, two ng-app will won't work on single page..you need to use `angular.boostrap`

Comment: @pankajparkar I only has one ng-app in my template. Only inserting ng-app into body tag, other then that none.

Comment: @AndroidBeginner I didn't get you..can you please elaborate more?